# How do I put a link, to an external website in a browser, in a button in a windows form application?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, hyperlink

I have a button, **BtnReadMore**, within a form named **RandomFacts**, that, when clicked, should open a specific link in the user's web browser.

The RandomFacts form does what the name implies. When a button is clicked, a random fact about a topic is generated and displayed in a rich text box. Certain facts can be read more about and a button will appear in the form, when one of these particular facts is generated, which will contain a link to a website for extended reading.

What code should I place within a button click method in order to achieve this effect?

Comment: If you want to open up the default WebBrowser, `Process.Start("http://www.SomeWebSite.com");`. Can't you have a WebBrowser Control in your Form? It'ld probably be nicer to have it all contained in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Process.Start method from [System.Diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.7.2) namespace for the purpose.

```
Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
```

This opens the URL in default browser. If you want to use a specific browser, you can do the following.

```
Process.Start("IExplore.exe","www.google.com"); //for IE
Process.Start("chrome.exe","www.google.com");   // for Chrome
```